# Find the complex function using the known information about its modulus on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find the fuction $f(z)$ that satisfies the condition
$$
|f(e^{-iz})|^2=21+12\cos z-8\cos 2z \, ?
$$
I see that it is
$$
\mathrm{Re}\, (21+12e^{iz}-8e^{2iz})
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{Re}\, (21+12e^{-iz}-8e^{-2iz})
$$
but how it can help me I don't know.

Comment: Are you certain they ask for _the_ function? If there is one, it isn't unique. It is under the additional assumption that it is analytic inside the unit circle and doesn't have zeroes there.

Comment: Obviously, the OP isn't interested in clarifying questions, they just want to have their homework done. Good luck, then!